# Python NLTK Brill Tagger does not have SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate, ProximateTokensTemplate, ProximateTagsRule, ProximateWordsRule

Tags: python, tags, nltk, pos-tagger

When i try importing,

> from nltk.tag.brill import SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate, ProximateTokensTemplate
>   from nltk.tag.brill import ProximateTagsRule, ProximateWordsRule

Python Throws Import Error,

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate'

What's the problem?

but this works

> from nltk.tag import brill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brill part of NLTK has been redesigned in NLTK 3. So all those classes you try to import do not exist any more.
See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/549

I'm looking for an example how to use the Brill Tagger but till now, I didn't find anything.

Comment: I too figured that out recently! Thanks.

Comment: I used the older version of the brill tagger to build !

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the templates from `nltk.tag.brill`.
There are four methods

- `nltkdemo18()`
- `nltkdemo18plus()`
- `fntbl37()`
- `brill24()`

which return sets of templates. From my evaluation `fntbl37()` is the best.

Here is some code:

```
Template._cleartemplates()
templates = fntbl37()
self._tagger = UnigramTagger(tagged_sents)
self._tagger = BrillTaggerTrainer(self._tagger, templates, trace=3)
self._tagger = self._tagger.train(tagged_sents, max_rules=250)
```

I hope it helps.