# Training Brill tagger in nltk, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate'

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am training Brill tagger against conll2000 corpus. For reasons that I don't understand, I am having the following error:

brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (1,1)),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate'

I am following [this] (http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-3/)  tutorial. The code is below:

```
import nltk.tag
from nltk.tag import brill

raubt_tagger = backoff_tagger(train_sents, [nltk.tag.AffixTagger,
    nltk.tag.UnigramTagger, nltk.tag.BigramTagger, nltk.tag.TrigramTagger],
    backoff=nltk.tag.RegexpTagger(word_patterns))

templates = [
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (1,1)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (2,2)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (1,2)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (1,3)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateWordsRule, (1,1)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateWordsRule, (2,2)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateWordsRule, (1,2)),
    brill.SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateWordsRule, (1,3)),
    brill.ProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateTagsRule, (-1, -1), (1,1)),
    brill.ProximateTokensTemplate(brill.ProximateWordsRule, (-1, -1), (1,1))
]

trainer = brill.FastBrillTaggerTrainer(raubt_tagger, templates)
braubt_tagger = trainer.train(train_sents, max_rules=100, min_score=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those errors likely because you are using NLTK 3, where some of the Brill tagger code was changed, including the templates. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323409/python-nltk-brill-tagger-does-not-have-symmetricproximatetokenstemplate-proxima) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous commenter mentioned, there was a change to the Brill tagger with NLTK 3.  I've created a fork of the nltk-trainer repository here:

https://github.com/burgersmoke/nltk-trainer

The only change in this fork for the Brill tagger was in this file:

https://github.com/burgersmoke/nltk-trainer/blob/master/nltk_trainer/tagging/training.py